# Как сделать чтобы бот направлял пользователя в группу на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как перенаправить пользователя после нажатия Reply кнопки в групу или канал (без добавления, просто направить) в aiogram

```
from aiogram import types, Router, F, Bot


router = Router()
router.message.filter(F.chat.type.in_({"private"}))


@router.message(F.text == "Living library")
async def link_living_library(message: types.Message, bot: Bot) -> None:
    pass
```

Пробовал через webbrowser, но мне не совсем подходит данный вариант так как открыется в браузере, а нужно что б в телеграме. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button = InlineKeyboardButton('text', url='https://url канала')
keyboard.add(button)
```

Также нужно импортировать модули:

```py
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
```

Тогда кнопка будет рядом с клавиатурой)

**Подробнее о кнопках тут:** [тык](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter5.html)

Comment: Ну как? Сработало?

Comment: Нет, я хочу сделать через Reply кнопку, а не Inline